# Should there be a place to check the quality of your question before posting?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I've recently had a question [put on hold,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336326/do-dying-asymptotes-leave-holes-in-iterated-asymptote-functions) and in retrospect, I can see how the people who put it on hold would have felt compelled to do so, and I don't want to argue this specific case.

But I do feel as though if there was a place that I could have put the question first, it could have saved a lot of time and the embarrassment of having my question put on hold. I wouldn't be looking for an answer there but just advice on how to make it a better question.

I also see questions that are poorly phrased, with horrible syntax become sorts of roast-fests for the asker, and while I can't find an example right now, I'm sure other people have seen these too. I cannot believe that anybody truly means to put out bad questions, but often, I find myself deleting drafts of questions on weird phenomenon just because I don't know the jargon or how to state a certain piece of logic.

While for the creation of this editing place, I do have to voice my doubts, since it will likely become a place of horrid, unworthy questions that people put no thought into simply because somebody else will make it a formal masterpiece for them. I also believe that it will be a place that most questions are answered, since in a lot of cases, it'll be easier to simply answer the question rather than fixing it.

Comment: I believe that someone made a chat room for this, but I don't have the link. Perhaps this comment will lead to a good Samaritan posting the link to it.

Comment: I guess [the question triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), if implemented in Math.SE, would help here. Heck, it might do exactly this (and alleviate other problems as well).

Comment: My advice would be more to go ahead and post something, assuming it is a Question whose answer matters to you.  Putting the Question on hold is not a final disposition, and while on-hold it can be commented and edited with improvements. I can understand wanting to avoid a "messy" public editing session of this kind, but it is a learning experience of value to Readers as well as yourself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Any info on will this be implemented? This sounds like a really good idea.